# What is the correct term for this person?

Tags: terminology

What do you call a person or what is the job title for a person who can fix or repair anything?

Comment: Jack of all trades? Handyman (for males).

Comment: @trw I would use *handyman* for both sexes.

Comment: Colloquially, "Mr Fixit".

Comment: Why do you think there is a “correct” answer possible here?

Comment: "Handyman" is the most common term.  150 or so years ago it was "tinkerer", I understand, but that term has since come to mean a hobbyist who tinkers around.

Comment: I'd avoid 'Jack of all trades', which might be taken as being sarcastic, because of the saying "Jack of all trades, master of none."

Answer (score 1):

The word for such a person would be 'Handyman'.

Comment: Definition and a reference link would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as job titles: If you kept company with folks who live in rented apartments, in NY, you would often hear the phrase - "I have to call "The Super".  *Super* is short for *superintendent* who is usually a resident of the building, hired by the property owner, to do household repairs for the tenants.